# Is it possible to use Spacy for negation detection in the French language?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, negation

In negspacy, one can detect negations. I have done the following for the English language.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.add_pipe("negex", config={"ent_types":["PERSON","ORG"]})
doc = nlp("She does not like London but likes Paris.")
for e in doc.ents:
    print(e.text, e._.negex)
```

But is this also possible for the French language? I know there exists a French vocabulary such as `nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")`, but is there an out of the box model to do negation detection in French or should one train this from scratch or finetune a pretrained model?